# Django CharField not defaulting to empty string

Tags: django

The Django docs say:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as NULL.

So I set up my model like

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_num = models.TextField()
    street_predir = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')    # optional
    street_name = models.TextField()
    street_suffix = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='')    # optional
    street_postdir = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')   # optional
```

and then create an object that's missing the optional fields

```
raw_address = '1234 MAIN ST'
# Run this through an address parser - this returns a dictionary of address components
# Optional fields are returned as None if not present
components = parser.parse(raw_address)
address = Address(**components)
address.save()
```

But I'm getting the error

```
null value in column "street_predir" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (8633570, 2057 ANCHOR ST, 2057, null, ANCHOR, ST, null, null, null, ANCHOR ST, null, null, )
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't defaulting to an empty string? FWIW I'm using Django 1.7.4 and a Postgres DB.

Comment: No need for `default=''`, you should rather use `blank=True` to allow empty values in forms. Can you post the traceback and possibly the contents of `from django.db import connection; print(connection.queries)`?

Comment: Can you also post the code that creates the object, or any custom save methods? Somewhere, you're explicitly setting `None` instead of an empty string.

Comment: The "... will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL" part does not seem to hold anymore:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4136#comment:42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Run this through an address parser - this returns a dictionary of address components
# Optional fields are returned as None if not present
components = parser.parse(raw_address)
```

This explicitly sets the value to `None`, which is directly translated to `NULL` in the database. You should remove all keys which have value `None` or replace the value with `''` instead:

```
components = {k: v for k, v in components.items() if v is not None}
```

This will only set the non-empty components, and the others will default to an empty string instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In the quoted text you pasted, a bit after it states:

> you will also need to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as the null parameter only affects database storage (see blank).

For strings you should use `blank=True`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    required_string = models.CharField()
    optional_string = models.CharField(blank=True, default="")
```

Comment: I'm not using any forms or the admin site though - this is all through code. I tried setting `blank=True` and I'm still getting the same "violates not-null constraint" :/

Comment: Dont' forget about `null=True`

Comment: @C.B. "Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. " - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#null